# CDH3u6 Single Node cluster DataNode start throw error

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I get the following error -

```
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = atuls-macbook-air.local/192.168.0.22
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.2-cdh3u6
STARTUP_MSG:   build = git://ubuntu-slave01/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CDH3u6-Full-RC/build/cdh3/hadoop20/0.20.2-cdh3u6/source -r efb405d2aa54039bdf39e0733cd0bb9423a1eb0a; compiled by 'jenkins' on Wed Mar 20 11:45:36 PDT 2013
************************************************************/
2014-10-31 09:06:49,252 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:544)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:1757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:1750)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1618)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getLocal(FileSystem.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1680)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1796)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "558:feed::1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.<init>(DnsClient.java:125)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.<init>(Resolver.java:61)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.getResolver(DnsContext.java:570)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:430)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:231)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:139)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLDirContext.getAttributes(GenericURLDirContext.java:103)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbServiceLocator.getKerberosService(KrbServiceLocator.java:87)
    at sun.security.krb5.Config.checkRealm(Config.java:1295)
    at sun.security.krb5.Config.getRealmFromDNS(Config.java:1268)
    at sun.security.krb5.Config.getDefaultRealm(Config.java:1162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosName.<clinit>(KerberosName.java:81)
    ... 14 more

2014-10-31 09:06:49,253 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at atuls-macbook-air.local/192.168.0.22
************************************************************/
```

Do I need a special user or is something wrong in my setting? Is there a setting that I am missing? I changed the directory permissions.

Here is my hdfs-site.xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.permissions</name>
     <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <!-- Immediately exit safemode as soon as one DataNode checks in. 
       On a multi-node cluster, these configurations must be removed.  -->
  <property>
    <name>dfs.safemode.extension</name>
    <value>0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.safemode.min.datanodes</name>
     <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <!-- specify this so that running 'hadoop namenode -format' formats the right dir -->
     <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
     <value>/Users/atul/hadoop_dfs/name</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
     <value>/Users/atul/hadoop_dfs/data</value>
  </property>

  <!-- Enable Hue Plugins -->
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.plugins</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.thriftfs.NamenodePlugin</value>
    <description>Comma-separated list of namenode plug-ins to be activated.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.plugins</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.thriftfs.DatanodePlugin</value>
    <description>Comma-separated list of datanode plug-ins to be activated.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.thrift.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:10090</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I would appreciate any help in this regard. I need to run CDH3u6 hence this version.

Comment: Did you upgrade your namenode recently?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand - upgrade the name node comment. It is a simple single node setup.

Comment: Did you run a 'sudo service hadoop namenode -upgrade' or 'hadoop-deamon.sh namenode -upgrade'? This is what is call a manual cluster update

Comment: No I did not upgrade anything.